# Meaning of parameters are transferred when backend receive the special character in springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, special-characters

I am having some problems about parameters ('<','>','&') are transferred to'<','&gt','&'. Is there a solution that ensure the parameters do not be transferred since I want to restore some special character in my database.

[This is my frontend code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA9Sw.png)

I receive parameters by PubParams[This is my backend code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFZzd.png)

[This is my debugging result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxUB3.png)

As you can see , I receive a escaped character( &lt &gt). my origin parameter is < >.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is getting URL encoded.

You could use `URLDecoder.decode()` on what you receive.